# How to GroupBy based on condition

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to group a collection of data with the key being one of two properties, that isn't null. One of the properties is null, the other is not, but it's not the same each time.

What I'd like to do is something like this:

```
repo.Data.GroupBy(d => d.SomeNumber != null ? d.SomeNumber: d.SomeString)
```

So if SomeNumber (nullable int) isn't null, group by it, else group by SomeString.

Comment: I guess `d.SomeNumber != null ? d.SomeNumber.ToString() : d.SomeString` should work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are receiving is probably:

> There is no implicit conversion between 'Nullable' and 'string'

GroupyBy expects comparable types, so you need to make sure your `? :` returns two values of the same type.

```
repo.Data.GroupBy(d => d.SomeNumber!= null ? d.SomeNumber.ToString(): d.SomeString);
```

or depending on what `SomeString` is

```
repo.Data.GroupBy(d => d.SomeNumber!= null ? d.SomeNumber: int.Parse(d.SomeString));
```

If you need to make sure `1` (`Nullable<int>`) and `"1"` (`string`) are **not** grouped together, I'd recommend this approach:

```
repo.Data.GroupBy(d => d.SomeNumber??(object)d.SomeString);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could either use

```
repo.Data.GroupBy(d => d.SomeNumber != null ? d.SomeNumber.ToString() : d.SomeString);
```

or if this doesn't work (or is too ambigous) you can use `Tuple`:

```
repo.Data.GroupBy(d => new Tuple<int?,string>(d.SomeNumber, d.SomeString))
```

or you cast everything to `object` (though that would involve boxing the `int`):

```
repo.Data.GroupBy(d => d.SomeNumber != null ? (object)d.SomeNumber : (object)d.SomeString));
```

Comment: I like the second approach, but in this case it wouldn't work because it would always group by **both** values, even if `SomeNumber` is **not** `null`.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer added a third way that should avoid that.

Comment: Just had the same thought ;)